# How decide the size of svg file for using as VectorDrawable for android?

Tags: android, svg

I was using pngs instead of svg, now I want to move .
When we are using from android asset the material icons ,the default size 24dp, I know we can modify it.
Now I want to know that if the  png size for an icon is
52x62 hdpi
26x31 ldpi
......
saving resource in svg format the size how much should be?
and in layout xml we are going to use the xml as wrap_content yes?

Answer (score 4):

For VectorDrawables, it doesn't really matter.  They might have default width and height values of 24dp, but those values will be overridden by whatever size they eventually get drawn at.

Comment: You mean overriding  width and height in layout xml ?

Comment: Yes. For instance in an `<ImageView>`

Comment: It means we will not use wrap_content and instead of it set width and height in dp ?
and  that means we need to know the physical size of resource 
(the proportion )to set it?

Comment: If you are using your own VectorDrawable (instead of a material icon), then it probably won't be 24dp, it will be whatever you make it (52x62 or whatever).  You can still override it with `width` and `height` on your `ImageView`.  You can control how it gets scaled in the `ImageView` with `scaleType`.

Comment: for example if the png I have used 52x62 for mdpi , 78x93 for hdpi ,104x122 for xhdpi,now using svg ,the size in dp how much should be, if I want to use as src for ImageView with wrap_content,

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the values are in the VectorDrawable. Just what values you use for width and height in the ImageView.

Comment: You mean using svg ,we need to set dpi values to  width and height ?
If possible to create svg file in a way that without giving dpi sizes, using wrap_content it could fit?
One more question, when the svg is zoomed it's not lose any quality, in that case we could create 24dp  svg and could use in 200dp ImageView? if yes ,why it is limited to create max 200dp svg or why it exists opportunity to create 200dp svg ,when in 20dp everyting could be concetrated.

Comment: (1) I don't understand. (2) Yes, make sure your SVG has a viewBox. (3) Yes. (4) That's not a limit, it is a recommendation. Rendering might be slow if it is too big. But if it is fast for you, or you don't mind if it is slow. Then go for it.

Comment: 1.when the svg is zoomed it doesn't lose quality,why we need to create 200dp svg ,as we could create 24dp and it could do the same functionality and then set 200dp to ImageView.?
2.when we have a design in psd ,which size (screen unit in px, for mdpi,hdpi,...)should be taken account for creating svg, which we could use in project without setting dp value to ImageView container and using wrap_content.?

Comment: The ratio of dp to (size+dpi) varies for different devices. So I don't think there is a good answer for your second question.

Comment: I have posted a new question ,please help :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083846/how-to-use-svgs-in-selector-for-pre-lolipop-version