# How to use svgs in selector for pre lollipop version?

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I used selector for checkbox it works, but it causes problems for pre lollipop  version

```
<selector xmlns:android="...">
    <item android:state_checked="true"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked_icon" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon" />
</selector>




<CheckBox
 android:button="@drawable/terms_checkbox"/>
```

it causes resourcNotFoundexception, How to solve the problem, is there any solution?

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class CheckBox

```
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/terms_service1.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020121
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)

                                                                      at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:74)
                                                                      at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:68)


Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Draw
```

Comment: Works for me in Android Version 4.3.

Comment: I'm testing on Emulator android version 4.3.1
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:

Comment: What is the buildToolsVersion used in gradle??

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

Comment: Also set vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: all these  done but it crashes.

Comment: Can you post full error log??

Comment: I have added the main parts of log .I have updated questions ,please review

Comment: @sJy the logs where clear for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115897/discussion-between-sjy-and-a-a-i-a).

Comment: This Android bug report might be of help: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210745&pageId=109201119303080409719

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    Drawable d = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(this, R.drawable.terms_checkbox);
    checkBox.setButtonDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true 
    }
}
```

2) In your Application class:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

3) Use app:buttonCompat insted of android:button for CheckBox 
or buttonCompat insted of android:button your in style.xml

4) In my case I needed to add

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

parameters in my CheckBox for onClick reaction.

5) And in my case I  needed to use 
`androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` instead of `CheckBox` in xml layout.

The [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-vector-assets-in-android-apps-4318fd662eb9) was helpfull.